# Reverse-i-search doesn't continue

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, ssh, search

I wanted to use the reverse-i-search as usual by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to search my last ssh command. When I tried, I was only able to write "ss" but not continue with "h". Additionally when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> again, nothing happens. Does anybody have an explanation?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and in the pasttime this worked fine (on my other computer with the same os)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this:

> [...] first press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then start typing the command or any part of the command that you are looking for. You'll see an auto-complete of a past command at your prompt. If you keep typing, more specific options will appear. **You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> again as many times as you want to, this goes back in your history to the previous matching command each time**
>
> Once you see a command you like, you can either run it by pressing return, or start editing it by pressing arrows or other movement keys.

Source: [Navigating Bash History with Ctrl+R](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/navigating-bash-history-with-ctrlr).

Comment: I tried again with other commands. Some work. So my explanation would be, that since I used the ssh command the last time, I deleted the terminal history. Question: Does the input prompt of ctrl r stop, if the character combination never occured before? meaning I could not write "h" because "ss" occured, but not "ssh"?

Comment: @aldorado You can try "ss" if this didn't ocured in the time, you will get the right command. If `sh` ocurred in this time, then press again Ctrl+R and type again "ss" and so on.

Answer (score 4):

From: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal

> An extremely handy tool :: Incremental history searching

in terminal enter:

```
gedit  ~/.inputrc
```

then copy/paste and save:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[C": forward-char
"\e[D": backward-char
```

FROM now on and many agree this is the most useful terminal tool saves you a lot of writing/memorizing... all you need to do to find a previous command is to enter say the first 2 or 3 letters and upward arrow will take you there quickly. Say I want:

```
for f in *.mid ; do timidity "$f"; done
```

all I need to do is enter

```
fo
```

and hit upward arrow. Command will soon appear!

Comment: Nice link indeed! Can you explain what the single components of the commands "\e[X" mean?

Comment: Hi.. they are keyboard key references. I don't know WHY they named them like `\e[X`, but here's an article explaining HOW:
http://blog.theliuy.com/inputrc-keyboard-mapping-config-file/

Comment: Found it!
http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_90.html#SEC97

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in terminal. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to toggle forward when searching for commands in the terminal. For current session- add it to .bashrc to disable it permanently.

```
stty -ixon

ctrl+r -> reverse i search

ctrl+s -> i search
```